# Inactive links in ListView ArrayAdaptor

Tags: android, android-listview

I have a list of around 2500 items in a ListView object. I would like for some of those items to be visible, but greyed out. An activity launches for the ones that aren't greyed out (in my case, this is an AlertDialog). I'd like (for example) the first 500 items to be active and to have the usual behaviour, whilst the other items are greyed out and clicking on them does nothing.

What I'm trying to create is a trial version of a ListView app, so that the user can only access some of the items in the list for demonstration purposes.

What would be the simplest way of going about this? I can only think of having two lists that are appended to each other (the first being active, the second not). Ideally I would actually have interdigitated lists, such that (for example) every third item is active and the others are not, but I'll settle for two separate groups that run on the same list if that would be too complicated.

Comment: I would go and implement custom list adapter. It is much more easy and flexible to work with. In the custom adapter you can set the color for each item that you like based on some condition. Also, when you click on item, you can check the condition again and decide whether to show a dialog or not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply extend whatever adapter you are using and add this simple check in `getView()`:

```
@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    View view = super.getView(position, convertView, parent);

    if(position < 500) {
        view.setClickable(false);
        view.setEnabled(true);
    }
    else {
        view.setClickable(true);
        view.setEnabled(false);
    }

    return view;
}
```

I did your simple check (if the row is in the first 500) then changed a couple characteristics.

- `setEnabled()` turns the text grey when it is `false`.
- `setClickable()` when `true` this prevents the ListView from receiving the TouchEvent.

Hope that helps!